# Docker Container A (React APP) is not able to fetch data from Container B (ExpressJS) in the same Docker network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express

I have two containers, a React app hosted by an NGINX image and a NodeJS Express app. Both are on the same Docker network.

[image]

The React app should be fetching data via express routes from the Express app on port 8082. But it is not working. The error is:

> Could not load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

[image]

172.19.0.3 is the Docker Network IP of my Express App.

However, I have exposed port 8082 from the Express App to the Docker host. When I try to get data from the public IP of my host, it works.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what is preventing the React container from successfully fetching the data?

I tried docker exec <container_id_or_name> netstat -an | grep 8082 and ping commands inside the container. Unfortunately the commands are not suported by the images of the containers.

Comment: Haveyou tried host.docker.internal instead of ip adress

Comment: Why are you sending requests to a network? You should either send the request to the other container's IP or instead of its IP, use the other container's name.

Comment: Plus, try using a container orchestrator depending on the scale of your application, to make life easier. e.g. Docker Compose, Docker Swarm, Kubernetes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your React app isn't running in the container. It's running in your browser.

So it can't use the bridge network addresses. Only processes running inside the containers can do that.

You need use the mapped port of the Express app, i.e. `207.180.207.139:8082`.

Comment: I know. I open the react app in my browser, but the app is not able to fetch the data from the express app.

Comment: @LukeNukem Your error message says that you're trying to fetch data from `172.19.0.3:8082` which is the Docker network IP address. You can't use that from the browser.